# Can I install Bosh-Lite on an Openstack VM without using Virtualbox?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

**Doubt**: Can Bosh-Lite be deployed on an OpenStack VM without using Virtualbox ?

**Use Case**: Want to have a Bosh-Lite setup that can be used by CI systems

I am not sure if Bosh-Lite can be directly installed on an OpenStack VM or I need to setup VirtualBox first (Does this another layer of virtualization work ?)

I followed the docs @ https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite and currently stuck at defining the parameters for three variables for Openstack CPI and getting the following error:

```
    Parsing release set manifest '/root/workspace/bosh-deployment/bosh.yml':
  Evaluating manifest:
    - Expected to find variables:
        - default_key_name
        - net_id
        - private_key
```

Answer (score 0):

No, bosh-lite is explicitly a virtual box solution where you don't have a full IaaS/CPI like OpenStack

> BOSH Lite v2 is a Director VM **running in VirtualBox** (typically locally)

Is the very first line on the docs you linked to.

You can run full blown bosh on openstack with very little effort though.

https://bosh.io/docs/init-openstack.html